# Flash Player (AS3) and HTML attributes

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I'm curious, is it possible for a flash player (SWF) object on an HTML page to update the HTML attributes directly, or would I have to use a script to accomplish this?

I tried searching Google for this, but couldn't find anything saying either way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `ExternalInterface` API which allows you to execute JavaScript in the containing page from the SWF.

> From the ActionScript you can do the following on the HTML page:
>
> - Call any JavaScript function.
> - Pass any number of arguments, with any    names.
> - Pass various data types (Boolean, Number, String, and so on).
> - Receive a return value from the JavaScript function.

See documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use that, but it looks like it's the only way.